# Checking if request to Apache webserver is https or not in tomcat behind apache web server

Tags: apache, tomcat, ssl, https

I am running tomcat behind apache webserver. Apache webserver receives the https request and send the http request to tomcat. I want to know if there is a way to know if the request to the apache server was https or just http. Is there a way to know? Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

If you have set up reverse proxying using AJP then you can simply call request.isSecure() to see if the request was HTTPS.

See The [Apache Tomcat Connector - Reverse Proxy HowTo](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/generic_howto/proxy.html) for details.

Comment: we are using AJP and request.isSecure() was still saying only http because the proxy gets the https request but does a http call to tomcat. We fixed this issue by passing a request header with the value 'http' or 'https' based on if its a http or https request that Apache receives. Thanks for the response!

Comment: The reverse proxy should be making a AJP call to Tomcat, not HTTP.  The Tomcat AJP connector make sure that all of the information about the original request is passed to the servlet engine.  It sounds like maybe you weren't using an AJP connector on the Tomcat side.